# clicked div to slide with the transition div

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

I have a scenario where I need to click on a `div` which will give me another `div` with some transition, but the problem is the clicked `div` is getting hidden upon the transition `div`. I need the clicked `div` to slide with the transition `div` with the same transition effect. Below is what I have tried:

HTML:

```
<div id='outerdiv' ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
    <div  ng-click="myValue=!myValue">RIGHT</div>
        <div id="one" class='animate-hide'  ng-hide="myValue">
            this is just a sample div
        </div>
    {{myValue}}
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp1", ["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.myValue=true;
});
```

CSS:

```
.animate-hide {

-webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
      top: 10px;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  left: -100%;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dvpdnjps/635/)

Comment: Add position: relative; to #outerdiv and also try to adjust (.animate-hide) top:10px to 20px;

Answer (score 0):

Modify the HTML to the following:

```
<body ng-app="myApp1">
<div id='outerdiv' ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
        <div id="one" class='animate-hide'  ng-hide="myValue"> 
            this is just a sample div
        </div>
    <div id="main" style="width:50px" ng-click="myValue=!myValue">RIGHT
    {{myValue}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I would also add a transition-duration for the `div` that has the ng-click attribute. Instead of setting the directional transition to `left,` change it to `margin-left`. Also add `float:left` to both the `main` div and the `one` div:

```
.animate-hide {
 -webkit-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -moz-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    -o-transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
    transition:all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  line-height:20px;
  opacity:1;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background:white;
  margin-left:0;
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  margin-left:-100%;
  opacity:0;
  padding:0 10px;
}

#one{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  transition-duration:.5s;
}

#main{
  float:left;
  width:100px;
  transition-duration:.5s;
}
```

Note: I also added set widths for both of the elements required to animate.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dvpdnjps/636/

**ANOTHER SOLUTION**

If you need to keep the hidden div positioned absolute, you can make the following changes to your JS code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp1", ["ngAnimate"]);
app.controller("MyCtrl", function ($scope) {
$scope.myValue = true;
$scope.changeVal = function(){
  var mainDiv = document.getElementById('main');
  $scope.myValue = $scope.myValue == true ? false : true;
  if(!mainDiv.classList.contains('moved'))
    {
            mainDiv.classList.add("moved");
    } else {
            mainDiv.classList.remove('moved');
    }
}
});
```

And then add this to your CSS:

```
.moved{
  margin-left:120px;
  transition-duration:.5s;
  padding-left:15px;
}
```

Then you have to make sure the changeVal function will be called on click:

```
<body ng-app="myApp1">
<div id='outerdiv' ng-controller="MyCtrl" >
        <div id="one" class='animate-hide'  ng-hide="myValue"> 
            this is just a sample div
        </div>
    <div id="main" style="width:50px" ng-click="changeVal();">RIGHT

    {{myValue}}
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Here I am moving the "RIGHT" div along with the hidden div. This way you can make your hidden div stay absolutely positioned.

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dvpdnjps/639/

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there in fiddle u have removed position:absolute and z-index:1
but i need to apply the and if i keep that this transition is not working

Comment: If you make the position absolute it will not move the other div.  You can animate both at the same duration.  You can move the result  div lower so the absolute div doesn't cover it.

Comment: ya but if i keep position absolute my content in the rght side is getting disturbed which i dont want to happen

Answer (score 0):

I made 3 changes and got a cool effect, but I'm not sure what you want in this transition. Trying to get an animation correctly for someone else is just as hard as trying to describe it.

#### Changes

```
.animate-hide {
  ...
  margin: 0 0 15px 0;
  position: relative;
  ...
}

.animate-hide.ng-hide {
  ...
  transition: all cubic-bezier(0.250, 0.460, 0.450, 0.940) 2s;
  ...
}
```

I removed the vendor prefixes, they are no longer needed, see [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions)

<kbd>[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/9kwns9u3/)</kbd>

Comment: Really appreciated

but i also need that right to move aside along with div and when i click back on that it should come to same position